# Typo3 RealURL: Format datetime

Tags: php, datetime, typo3, datetime-format, realurl

Assuming the following Typo3 RealURL setup:

```
'news' => array(
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
        ),
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
        ),
        array(
                'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                'lookUpTable' => array(
                        'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                        'id_field' => 'uid',
                        'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(title, "-", datetime)',
                        'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                        'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                        'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                'strtolower' => 1,
                                'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                        ),
                        'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                        'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                        'autoUpdate' => 1,
                        'expireDays' => 180,
                ),
        ),
),
```

It's about this line: `'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(title, "-", datetime)',`

I need to format the timestamp.

What I already tried: `'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(title, "-", DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d'))',`

+++ some more text +++ some more text +++ some more text +++

Comment: Would you mind to show the desired output and the output you currently have.

Comment: Desired output: `http://www.example.net/news/article/my-article-2014-10-22/` Current output: `http://www.example.net/news/article/-aed1a14f04/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the MySQL date formatting functions:

```
'alias_field' => 'CONCAT(title, "-", DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(datetime)))',
```

This will convert the Unix timestamp to a MySQL DateTime and format it as date only.

See the [Date and Time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) functions of MySQL for more information.